# upload Docker-image to Plesk

Tags: docker, plesk

I have 2 repositories in hub.docker.com.
One (rep1) created from hub by pressing "Create repository".
Second (rep2)- by pushing from local. And I can pull the second successfully.

But, using Docker extention in Plesk, I cant find an image from second repository. I can find only rep1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding the description in docker-repository ("bla-bla")